# Checking connection between device and com port

Tags: java, serial-port

I am developing a program in Java which I had to check a device is hook up in com port of the computer or not, I tried javax.comm ,rxtxcomm api but did not get success.

Comment: Please give us the code you used.

Answer (score 1):

Check the availability of the com port. If it's busy, then you have a device hooked up

Comment: Thanks for reply,But It is not work because I open the COM port so it is not come busy at starting . Code is follweing CommPortIdentifier port_id = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(serial_port_name_);
serial_port = (SerialPort)port_id.open("Gps",2000);
serial_port.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN);
serial_port_.setSerialPortParams(speed,
                             SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                             SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                             SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);